# Message: Error Code -3: Invalid node returning by Aerospike C# client

Tags: c#, aerospike

I have a cluster of 14 nodes (all healthy) and running on Aerospike version Build: 3.16.0.6

The issue is Aerospike C# client (installed latest version 3.6.6) is returning for very few requests "Error Code -3: Invalid node". There is no other information passed about the actual invalid node. How to find this invalid node and why this error only occurs for few requests whereas the majority are working fine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do any of these conditions apply? https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-c-client-error-code-3/4160/3 and are there any wrong seed IPs (ie private vs. public IP) configured in the client seed list?